# matplotlib error: from inspect import Parameter ImportError: cannot import name 'Parameter'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just installed matplotlib using Anaconda because I need to plot a graph. I just imported it and literally I wrote:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle("Error rates / tree depth")
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(2,2)
```

When I run the file, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/xxxxxxx/ASSIGNMENTS/hw2/handout/decisionTree_working_not_cleaned.py", line 5, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Users/xxxxxxxxxxx/anaconda3/envs/ML35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 125, in <module>
    from inspect import Parameter
ImportError: cannot import name 'Parameter'
```

Any help? 
Thanks!

Comment: If you named a file `inspect.py`, pick a different name.

Comment: Other possibilities: maybe you're on a Python 2 environment you horribly screwed up, or you edited standard library files you shouldn't have.